# Pagination with $_POST and $_SESSION

Tags: pagination, query, session, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I have a page on my site where in the left column is a set of checkboxes representing taxonomies and in the right column is a list of posts that fall into the selected taxonomies. The user is able to check and uncheck these boxes and submit a form which then shows the results in the right column. That works great, here is the simplified code I'm using:

```
    <?php session_start();

if (isset($_POST)) {
$_SESSION['filters'] = $_POST;
}
?>

<div id="sidebar">
    <form id="filters" method="POST">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter1" value="term1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter1" value="term2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter1" value="term3" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter2" value="term1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter2" value="term2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter2" value="term3" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="results">
    <?php
    //The query is here, which changes dynamically based on the boxes checked above
    I'm using $_SESSION['filters'] to call $_POST variables inside the query
    ?>
</div>
```

The problem is, when Wordpress does its navigation thing, it goes to a URL like mysite.com/thispage/page/2/ which doesn't retain the form values like I need it to. It resets them as if the form has not been submitted at all. How do I get the selected to values to follow the user when they navigate the results pages.

This is the first time I'm attempting to use sessions, so I could be on the wrong track altogether. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the next lines of code to `functions.php` file within active theme to start session.

```
function example_login() {

    if ( ! session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'example_login' );
```

and then Use `$_SESSION` to store the value of `$post`